# How long does Resalor keep before expiry?

Tags: prescription, expiration-dates, medications

Once a prescription for Resalor (Prucalopride) is filled, how long does it remain viable before its expiration date?

Comment: I think this might differ from country to country. Can you please specify which country are you asking about?